# Longest path approximation algorithm from a given node

Tags: algorithm, path, graph

I'm looking for an approximation algorithm for the following problem - I have an unweighted, undirected graph, with cycles, and want to find the longest path starting from a given node.
I do value speed over performance (so a O(n^5) algorithm would probably be an overkill).

This is not homework (I swear!) or work related, but I will appreciate any tip you might have.

Comment: is this for the google contest?  Thats how I got here, haha!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm looking for an approximation algorithm for the following problem ...

Scientists are looking for it as well.  They have also [proved](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02523689) that polynomial constant-factor approximation doesn't exist if P ≠ NP.  And the abstract of [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6VCT-47K2XSW-C&_user=10&_coverDate=08%2F01%2F2003&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1197939408&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=20541cff7bbdeb6005682aacb50ac2e0) article claims that it contains an approximation algorithm for your problem.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. I thought the generalized problem has a constant factor approximation algorithm.
What about restricting the problem even further, by having a maximum  number of neighbors which is constant?

Comment: @r0u1i, Whoops, the first article I linked also contains a proof that such restriction doesn't help :-).

Comment: Note though that NP-completeness result does not necessarily tell anything about the graph instances you work with. For example, SAT is NP-complete but huge SAT instances are solved routinely in industrial applications. Also, are your graphs planar? Can you restrict your (apparent) condition that you can visit a node only once? Does the process by which your graph is constructed give a hint to the nature of the longest paths?

Comment: It is planar, what can I do with that?